# Why does this javascript code work?

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Phrase-o-matic</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
body {
    font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
</style>
<script>

function makePhrases() {
    var words1 = ["24/7", "multi-Tier", "30,000 foot", "B-to-B", "win-win"];
    var words2 = ["empowered", "value-added", "oriented", "focused", "aligned"];
    var words3 = ["process", "solution", "tipping-point", "strategy", "vision"];

    var rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * words1.length);
    var rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * words2.length);
    var rand3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * words3.length);

    var phrase = words1[rand1] + " " + words2[rand2] + " " + words3[rand3];
    var phraseElement = document.getElementById("phrase");
    phraseElement.innerHTML = phrase;
}
window.onload = makePhrases;
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Phrase-o-Matic says:</h1>

<p id="phrase"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

This is an example from a book i am reading on javascript why does the:

```
var rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * words1.length);
    var rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * words2.length);
    var rand3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * words3.length);
```

generate values that always round down to an index value in the arrays `words1`, `words2` and `words3`? Why does it never get a value above the last index number of 4

Comment: Protip: `~~` = `Math.floor()`

Comment: They once said that for `||` over `OR`

Comment: Reading Head First HTML5, aren't you?

Comment: @MistressDavid: even the book's title is tricky )

Comment: yup lol @MistressDavid you got it

Comment: Math.random() return a random number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive). Math.floor round a number downward to its nearest integer example : `Math.floor(1.6) -> 1`

Answer (score 2):

`Math.random() * words1.length` means `[0, words1.length)`. So the value always smaller than `words1.length`.

Answer (score 1):

floor() rounds down (always down) to the nearest integer.
Math.random() generates a number greater than or equal to 0 and less than 1.

If the length is 4, random() will generate a number between 0 and 3.9999999999, and round down. So the value will always be a valid index (0 to 3 inclusive) for a 4-element array.

Answer (score 0):

Math.random() returns a value between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive). So you may get for instance 0.1234. You then multiply this by the length of the array which is 4 in this case. The lowest possible value is 0 * 4 = 0 and the highest possible value is 0.9999 * 4 < 4.

The floor function truncates the the number leaving only the integer part which will be in the range 0, 1, 2 or 3.

Answer (score 0):

[Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) return a float value in [0, 1), which means :

> from 0 (inclusive) up to but not including 1 (exclusive)

So Math.random() * 4 will be [0, 4), and [Math.floor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) means:

> the largest integer less than or equal to a number

So Math.floor([0,3.xxxx...]) means [0,3]